# Differences between two tables

Tags: sql

Data is like so, (table1 links up to table2) on table1.col2 = table2.col2

Based on that criteria,

Employee 5 below assigned to Area 1 in first table, however in second table that employee is not assigned to Area 1, so the result that would return would only be the first record of the first table (emp5, a1)

Example below

Table1

```
Col1    Col2
-------------
emp5     A1
emp6     A1
emp5     A2
```

Table2

```
Col1      Col2
--------------
emp7       A1 
emp6       A1
emp5       A2
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky.  You need employees who are in both tables.  Then you need to check that col2 is different on one of the rows.

The following does this comparison using `union all`:

```
select col1, col2, max(which)
from ((select col1, col2, 1 as which
       from table1 t1 
       where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.col1 = t1.col1)
      ) union all
      (select col1, col2, 2 as which
       from table2 t2
       where exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t2.col1 = t1.col1)
      )
     ) tt
group by col1, col2
having count(*) = 1
```

This will also tell you which table has the extra row.

Comment: srry, couldn't get it to work, theres an error near 'tt'

Comment: @user406151 . . . The error was a missing parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MINUS, it is more intuitive. The syntax can be different in SQL Server, MySQL or Oracle, like you can see http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/07/sql-server-except-clause-in-sql-server-is-similar-to-minus-clause-in-oracle/

But I like MINUS, for instance

```
select 
   t1.Col1,
   t1.Col2
from table1 t1
MINUS
select 
   t2.Col1,
   t2.Col2
from table2 t2
```

This way, you can think like sets (math)!

Comment: Is MINUS the same as ANSI SQL's EXCEPT?

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.* 
  from table1 
  left join table2 
    on table1.col1 = table2.col1 
   and table1.col2 = table2.col2 
 where table2.col1 is null
```

if you only want those from table 1 that are also assigned to another project then

```
select distinct table1.* 
  from table1 
  join table2 as t2not 
    on t2not.col1 =  table1.col1 
   and t2not.col2 <> table1.col2 
  left join table2 
    on table1.col1 = table2.col1 
   and table1.col2 = table2.col2 
 where table2.col1 is null
```